# SignalR - StartUp

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I am looking for the quick and dirty answer.  I am just blanking, and after staring at a screen for over 12 hours now, I think I am shot.

I want to do a simple SignalR application as a tutorial.  I found this [example](http://iwantmymvc.com/mvc-3-signalr-knockout-real-time-notifications), but I keep getting the error that tickets is undefined.  I have found a couple more, and keep getting the same error.  I compared the sample project to mine and I cannot find any descrepencies.

It seems as though `$.connection.ticketHub` or `$.connection.chat` are returning undefined objects.  Is there something special that I need to do with `/signalr/hubs`?  Any other thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: <script src="signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script> 
you should add this script code in Page. Because signalR needs to run the defination of script code.

Comment: Where's your code? Might make it easier to tell you what's wrong if we could actually see it.

Comment: I have the same problem and solved like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941595/signalr-signalr-hubs-giving-404-error

Answer (score 14):

You need to add the /signalr/hubs to the page, it's a javascript dynamically generated by SignalR containing method stubs for your hubs and the methods on the hubs.

So if you have a .NET-hub named `TestHub`, with a method called `SendMessage(string message)` javascript will be generated so you can from JavaScript call: `$.connection.testHub.sendMessage("some message to server");`

Point your browser to the url: /signalr/hubs, and you should get a javascript.

about 150 lines down you will see the ticketHub stub:

```
$.extend(signalR, {
   ticketHub: {
      _: {
          hubName: 'YourNameSpace.TicketHub',
          ignoreMembers: ['someMethod', 'namespace', 'ignoreMembers', 'callbacks'],
          connection: function () { return signalR.hub; }
      },
```

You can use Mozilla Firebug plugin or Chrome developer tools (wrench-icon->Tools->Developer Tools) to see what's sent to and returned from server.

EDIT: There was a bug in SignalR preventing /signalr/hubs to be correctly generated (it didn't generate the method stubs). https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/134

EDIT2: you could have a incorrect script tag, try:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or you haven't referenced the `SignalR.AspNet.dll` assembly. If I recall correctly it's that assembly that wires up the route to /signalr.

Comment: yes, you are correct, I am getting a 404 from the /signalr/hubs request.  the issue you pointed me to showed a fix, but downloading the project file and building it did not fix the issue.

Comment: I am now getting this after adding in `SignalR.AspNet.dll` ... `Could not load type 'SignalR.IJsonSerializer' from assembly 'SignalR, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`

Comment: Have you added the `SignalR.dll` assembly? Those are the required assemblies.

Comment: yes i have, does NuGet have the updated package for SignalR?  It only installs `SignalR.dll` and NOT `SignalR.AspNet.dll`, so adding that in gives me the error.  Is there something else NuGet is not installing that I would need? Or is installing the wrong dll for `SignalR.dll`?

Comment: Try the latest from GitHub (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR). You would probably have to change ClientId to ConnectionId in your code if you are using it.

Comment: Where would that change take place?

Comment: The Hub has a Context, and that context has a property previously called `ClientId`, which is now called `ConectionId` (replace  `Context.ClientId` with `Context.ConnectionId` if you used it)

Comment: I am not using this anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using IE8?

If you are, make sure you include a Json2 script ref above the signalR script:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/json2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(Get Json2 from Nuget)

Answer (score 3):

Lee Smiths answer was right on the money. I got the latest json2 from nuget and also make sure that you have the change in your web.config from the the signalR faq site:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your script tag to this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

With Visual Studio 2010 / MVC 3 /  Firefox Browser , my Index.cshtml is using SignalR just fine with the following

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I had another issue, but I did not have to add in the @Url.Content to the signalr/hubs
For simplicity on testing I also just have my class file in root of Controllers folder. 
I also have the following from Nuget

```
SignalR / SignalR.Js / SignalR.Server / SignalR.Hosting.AspNet / SignalR.Hosting.Common
```

(Not that you NEED all of those dependencies, but that is what I have)

Hope that helps someone...