# SignalR "signalr/hubs" giving 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am using SignalR(https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) in my project. From here https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs I got the idea how to use Hubs. But the "signalr/hubs" script is giving 404 error. Here is the url which becomes in View Source: http://localhost:50378/signalr/hubs giving 404 error

Here is my code:
Hub:

```
public class Test:Hub
{
    public void Start()
    {
        Caller.guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        Clients.show("test", Caller.guid);
    }
}
```

ASPX:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Title</title>
        <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../Scripts/jquery.signalR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                var test = $.connection.test;
                $("#btnTest").click(function () {
                    test.testMethod();
                });
                test.show = function (text, guid) {
                    if (guid != test.guid) //notify all clients except the caller
                        alert(text);
                };
                $.connection.hub.start(function () { test.start(); });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="HtmlForm" runat="server">
            <div>

            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
....
```

Comment: Are you using the sources or the package? I recommend using the package as the sources aren't fully stable at this point.

Comment: Also, what webserver are you using?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It could be that you haven't added a reference to `SignalR.AspNet.dll`. If I recall correctly it's responsible for adding the route to `/signalr/hubs`.

Comment: Has this assembly/library been renamed to SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.dll? I have used the Nuget package and I don't see any source named SignalR.AspNet.dll

Comment: I guess i'ts now Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb.dll

Comment: @AndréPena yep... it's here http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb/ I removed unused `DLL`s from the project using RSharper just to find that this DLL is used only during runtime. Ouch!

Answer (score 44):

Try call RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs() before RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes) in Global.asax.cs if you use MVC 4. It works for me.

```
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Comment: I've found resources that say adding RouteConfig, WebApiConfig, and FilterConfig registries can help, but I cannot find the resource to add to reference any of these. What reference must I make to include these?

Comment: Why does `MapHubs()` have to be called *before* `RegisterRoutes()`?

Comment: Because you need to add Hub to the route table before register the route table with MVC.

Comment: The "before" is important!

Comment: This works for me. I'm using ASP .NET MVC 4 targeting .NET Framework 4.0. It is a must that MapHubs() must be called before RegisterRoutes().

Comment: `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();` is now obsolete. `app.MapSignalR();` should be called on a `IAppBuilder` inside owin startup class.

Answer (score 14):

From the **SignalR 1.0.0 RC2** there is a README in the packages folder that says the Hubs route must be manually established. :)  Here is a snippet...

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MyWebApplication
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public void Application_Start()
        {
            // Register the default hubs route: ~/signalr
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is now obsolete and not necessary - see http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/releases/upgrading-signalr-1x-projects-to-20

Answer (score 14):

In my case, the main reason of this 404 is hubs were not properly mapped. `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();` is now obsolete. For mapping hubs you can create a startup class as below.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApplication1.Startup))]
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I've struggled with this problem too and finally got to the point that was causing the problem. First of all, I have to say that with SignalR v2 calling`RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();` inside Globalasax/Application_Start is obsolete and compiler even throws warning. Instead we now add a dedicated StartUp class with the following public method:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.MapSignalR();
}
```

All the configuration goes here.See the [documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc) for more info.

Now, after wasting many hours googling like a crazy I decided to throw an Exception inside the Configure method of the StartUp class I mentioned earlier. If no exception would be thrown then I'd understand that Owin does not even start. My guess was right. For some reason Owin was not starting or something was suppressing it. In my case it was this evil configuration setting in my web.config file:

```
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
```

I guess the name of the setting is pretty descriptive. Either remove this or change false to true.

Comment: This one just bit me. I must have added the setting myself years ago, while playing with SignalR and completely forgot about this settings. Thanks!

Comment: The web.config file change did it!
Spent hours of hair pulling on this, changing things here, changing there.

Comment: For me it was <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="AmbitionProjectBudgetTool.App_Start.IdentityConfig" /> Same result, added app.MapSignalR(); to IdentityConfig instead and everything worked.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem when running my code using the Visual Studio development server and it worked when I changed my project settings to use IIS Local Web Server.

[image]

There was a defect raised against this issue which David Fowler commented on. The problem will be fixed in future releases but right now this is the workaround.  I cant find the link to the bug at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

Have you just installed IIS? In this case you might have to reinstall it:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Answer (score 4):

Long story short: in my case I used [R# (ReSharper)](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), right clicked my project that uses SignalR and clicked Refactor => Remove Unused References. Watch out: this is a *[shoot in the foot](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shoot+in+the+foot)*. :D

It removed IMPORTANT DLL references from `SignalR` that are used only during runtime, that is, they are not necessary during compile time. Obviously R# only checks for compile time dependencies.

Namely these 2 references were missing:

1. Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb
2. Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb (without this one a breakpoint in `SignalR` OWIN Configuration method won't even be hit).

Removed the NuGet packages and then reinstalled them. Fixed the `/hubs` 404 issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to reference the JavaScript file with `@Url.Content`, assuming ou're using ASP.NET MVC3

Like:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

See the [SignalR FAQ on GitHub](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq)

**Edit:** As Trevor De Koekkoek mentioned in their comment, you do not need to add `@Url.Content` yourself if you're using MVC4 or later. Simply prepending the uri with `~/` suffices. For more information, check out [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531484/url-content-not-working-on-complex-urls).

Comment: This only applies to MVC3 or before.  The Url.Content is automatic with "~/" in MVC4 and later.

Answer (score 3):

This is a full answer from SignalR wiki (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq). It worked with me:

First, make sure you have a call to MapHubs() in Global.asax.

Please make sure that the Hub route is registered before any other routes in your application.

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
```

In ASP.NET MVC 4 you can do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

If you're writing an MVC 3 application, make sure that you are using Url.Content for your script references:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")"></script>
```

If you're writing a regular ASP.NET application use ResolveClientUrl for your script references:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>
```

If the above still doesn't work, make sure you have RAMMFAR set in your web.config:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks 
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>
this resolved my issue

Answer (score 1):

My project is ASP.net 4.0 C# Web App, testing environment is Windows Server 2012.

I had the same issue with 1.0.0 RC2, I did what Michael suggests and it works. Thanks.

@MatteKarla: When install SignalR 1.0.0 RC2 by NuGet, following references are added to project:

- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb

I have to add Microsoft.CSharp manually or following error will occurred during compile:

- Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported

Answer (score 1):

I had this 404 errors when i updated to Signalr 2.0 and deployed MVC project to the production server. Publishing project with the "delete all existing files prior to publish" option saved my problems.

hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I too came across this same issue on an ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms application. It worked on development servers, but not in production environments.
The solution of ensuring all requests/modules run in managed mode wasn't acceptable for us.

The solution we went down (better for ASP.NET Web Forms) is the following.
Add the following section to Web.Config:

```
<modules>
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  <!-- any other modules you want to run in MVC e.g. FormsAuthentication, Roles etc. -->
</modules>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps worth mentioning: I'm running a Web Forms application that uses it's own manual routing.  Since OWIN startup occurs after the routing tables have been set, the route for /signalr/hubs was never hit.  I added a rule to ignore routes (IE: let web forms do the routing) on any path that starts with "/signalr".  This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by switching the application pool .NET Framework Version from v2.0 to v4.0.

Answer (score 0):

may be because your hub class name is 'Test' and you are referring to 'test' in client side.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need the signalr/hubs file it is just to have easier debugging and straightforward way to call a function. see : [See what the generated proxy does for you](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#genproxy) , that is all. Things will work without it.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to **reinstall** all the **packages** and restore all the **dependecies.**

Open nuget powershell and use this command.

```
Update-Package -Reinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `app.MapSignalR();` in `Startup` class resolves the issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case (signalr was added to existing, big mvc project) the reason of not firing OWIN Startup.Configruation() were missing "dependedntAssembly" and wrong "targetFramwerork" version in web.config.

I have created simple signalR project from scratch and compared web.config files. 
What has helped us was:

1. Correction from 4.5 to 4.5.2 in

```
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" ... > 
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" ... >
```

2. adding dependent assemblies:

```
<dependentAssembly> 
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" /> 
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /> 
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" /> 
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /> 
</dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting that exception because my url hosting was wrong. I wrote "/chathub" but in my endpoint It said "/chat"