# 404 error on signalr/hubs and on jquery scripts

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, http-status-code-404, signalr

I've just started using `SignalR` with C#, seems intresting.

I've created an `ASP.NET Empty Web Application` and followed the tutorial mentioned below

I found [Getting Started with SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) tutorial on MSDN.

I've done all the steps mentioned in the tutorial. It seems to work on my local machine when it is being run on `ASP.NET Development Server`.

But when i Deploy the project to my `IIS7`, it doesnot work.

When i checked with the fiddler, it has the results of 404 on all the scripts files included into the html page.

Here is what the fiddler has shown [image]

Even i've found some suggestions from the posts on StackOverflow, which doesnot seem to work when i change my `web.config` file as well.

finally i've modified my `web.config` according to the [FAQ's of SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq).

Here is my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Global.asax file:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Register the default hubs route: ~/signalr/hubs 
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
        }
        // Rest of the Methods(Session_Start,Application_BeginRequest..) are empty
     }
```

I've also changed

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>
```

None of them seem to work either.

Do not hesitate to ask if any information required.

Any help would be appreciated

---

**Update**

As per the Aron suggestion, the following change is made to the `Global.asax` file

```
 RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/");
```

and now, the `jQuery` scripts seems to be loading and working as well.

Here is the updated error message when hosted on IIS, its from the `Console` tab of the Browser window.

```
SCRIPT5022: SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/hubs'></script>.
```

Comment: Please include your Global.asax.cs

Comment: Does MVC work on this server?

Comment: Try adding RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/"); to your global.asax

Comment: @dfowler I would assume so, given that its localhost.

Comment: I wouldn't assume anything. It's really a yes or no question. SignalR uses a route in ASP.NET and if routing isn't working then things like MVC wouldn't work either (hence the question).

Comment: You even get a 404 for the static javascript files. Does this server have ASP.NET installed? Why are the static files returning 404?

Comment: @dflower MVC does work on this server and SignalR also. I need it to work with IIS

Comment: `RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("Scripts/")` when i use this on Global.asax i got another error. This time its not the js files its the signalr/hubs. When i use logging into my scripts i could see `SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct,`.

Comment: So the jQuery scripts are loading? Yes?

Comment: @Aron Yes jQuery scripts are loading and working

Comment: reduced to a duplicate of [SignalR “signalr/hubs” giving 404 error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8942623/1808494)

Comment: @Aron But i dont see any dll with SignalR.AspNet.dll. I've got the SignalR through Nuget

Comment: Look in the solution folder/packages/

Comment: @Aron I've it there in the pacakges.config file `<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net40" />`

Comment: Sorry. Memory serves they don't include any asp code into the signalr package in case you self host. There is a separate package for that.

Comment: @Aron Can you please give a link to that package

Comment: @Aron I've done that in my pacakge manager console already. It works locally for me and when hosted on iis it doesn't

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25737/discussion-between-aron-and-karthik)

Comment: Does the version of .net its running on in IIS7 match the version its set to, i.e. your app pool could be v2 and your project v4.  Also check that the app pool identity has full permissions on the folder containing your files.

Comment: @user1166905 i got it running previous to your comments only

Answer (score 1):

There may have been problem with your IIS settings. Please try adding MIME type for .js extension. Refer this [link](http://forums.iis.net/t/1195352.aspx/1)

Answer (score 1):

404 error may occure when IIS could not handle extension less url

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN article demonstrates how to create SignalR applications in version 2.0. But you use signalr 1.0 and probably older verstion of visual studio. upgrade the visual studio and use nugget package manager to add signalr 2.0 requirements to your project. I think as a first try it is better to use asp.net web application instead of MVC ( as MSDN article ). So you will not have routing problem. I could run the sample with no problem.