# iis directory browsing cause signalr 404 Not Found error or not?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, http-status-code-404, signalr, signalr-hub

I write an asp.net 4.0 web application, `signalr2`, and after many trials and getting the 404 Error I decided to  change my scenario of `signalR` to a very simple sample in order to fix the issues on my server.

I was getting Error 404 for http://subdomain.domain.com/signalr. However, this sample works smoothly on my local computer.

1. I have  added web config      `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>`
2. I have changed the signalR script reference with resolveuri and many other types.
3. and added `route.maphub()` with cross domain origin in `global.asax`

I was trying all listing article but am getting Error 404. Also see
[Github signalr FAQ](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq) and [StackOverflow Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941595/signalr-signalr-hubs-giving-404-error).

Finally, I want to know if maybe the IIS directory browsing with disable status can cause this issue?

Answer (score 1):

MapHubs is a version 1 method- you need to use MapSignalR instead if you're using SignalR 2. See the upgrade tutorial for details:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/upgrading-signalr-1x-projects-to-20

Are you able to access your hubs folder? In Chrome (not IE, since it will just try to run the JS), navigate to /signalr/hubs on your server. This should show a JavaScript file.

Also, try adding these to your application's Startup class:

```
app.UseWelcomePage();
```

This should add a default page to your root directory.

Comment: in my local machine show javascript but dosent work on server.i try this way erlier

Comment: your given bounty is a mistake !