# SignalR Hub 404 Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, signalr-hub

I keep getting a error like this
GET http://localhost:1025/signalr/hubs net::ERR_ABORTED

I also Get this error as well GET http://localhost:1025/signalr/hubs 404 (Not Found)

Any Help would be appreciated

If you need more information please let me know

when I am

```js
 <script type="text/javascript" src="..\CodeFolder\jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="..\CodeFolder\lightbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="..\CodeFolder\jquery.signalR-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Comment: What's your page url? Did you call `MapSignalR`?

Comment: I have called in application start "RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs()"

Comment: What's your page url?

Comment: localhost:1025/MemebersPages/Stocks.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SignalR "signalr/hubs" giving 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941595/signalr-signalr-hubs-giving-404-error)

Answer (score 0):

Issue in your server code. Just put `app.UseSignalR(...)` before `app.UseSpaStaticFiles()` in `Startup.cs`